# Prove the following: $\langle v_i,u_i\rangle >0 $ for each $1 \le i\le n $.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(v_1 , _{...},v_n) $ be independent vectors over V - inner product space.
and Let $(u_1 , _{...},u_n) $  be the vectors after gram-shcmidt normalization procedure. 
Prove the following: $$\langle v_i,u_i\rangle >0 $$
for each $1 \le i\le n $. I have tried to show that $sp((v_1 , _{...},v_i)) \ne sp((u_1 , _{...},u_i)) $
if $\langle v_i,u_i\rangle =0 $ (because its greater than or equal to zero for every couple of vectors) but im stuck in the middle and can't find a way to proceed. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Tip: \langle and \rangle are mush better for inner product brackets. Compare $<a.b>$ vs $\langle a,b \rangle$

Comment: Yeah thanks, didn't know that, i'm new in this site :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $u_1,\dots,u_{i-1}$ have been chosen via the Gram-Schmidt process, then $u_i$ is constructed as follows: write
$$ v_i=u+w $$
where $w$ is the orthogonal projection of $v_i$ onto $\mathrm{span}(v_1,\dots,v_{i-1})=\mathrm{span}(u_1,\dots,u_{i-1})$, and let $$u_i=\frac{u}{||u||}$$
Note that $u$ is non-zero since $v_i\not\in \mathrm{span}(v_1,\dots,v_{i-1})$.

To show that $\langle v_i,u_i\rangle >0$, it is therefore enough to show that $\langle v_i,u\rangle >0$. But
$$ \langle v_i,u\rangle=\langle u+w,u\rangle=\langle u,u\rangle>0 $$
since $u$ and $w$ are perpendicular.

Comment: No, I meant $v_i$. Explicitly, $w=\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\langle v_i,u_j\rangle u_j$.

Comment: By the Gram-Schmidt procedure $u_i=v_i-w$ and thus $v_i=u_i+w$. This makes more sense [in the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process#The_Gram.E2.80.93Schmidt_process) if you look at the definition of $\mathbf{u}_k$. The $\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \text{proj}_{\mathbf{u}_j}\left(\mathbf{v}_k\right)$ part is what @carmichael561 is calling $w$.